# Execute Lua on shell and get memory size and execution time

Tags: php, shell, lua

For a project, I have to execute Lua scripts and I want some information about the execution: memory size, CPU time, and runtime. I didn't find anything about some of the parameters for the Lua compiler at lua.org. Does anyone know the parameters or a compiler with this features? Later on, I want to analyze my Lua scripts with PHP.

- Shell exec via PHP
- and get information back (mem size, cpu time, runtime)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To analyze your Lua script, just wrap it in the following lines of code:

```lua
local time_start = os.time()

--------------------------------------
-- Your script is here
-- For example, just spend 5 seconds in CPU busy loop
repeat until os.clock() > 5
-- or call some external file containing your original script:
-- dofile("path/to/your_original_script.lua")
--------------------------------------

local mem_KBytes = collectgarbage("count") -- memory currently occupied by Lua
local CPU_seconds = os.clock()                  -- CPU time consumed
local runtime_seconds = os.time() - time_start  -- "wall clock" time elapsed
print(mem_KBytes, CPU_seconds, runtime_seconds)
-- Output to stdout: 24.0205078125  5.000009  5
```

Now you can execute this script with shell command `lua path/to/this_script.lua` and analyze the last line printed to stdout to get the information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: Some extensions for more time resolution: If you have luasocket installed, you can use `socket.gettime` instead of `os.time` to get the time with millisecond instead of just second resolution. Using your shell's `time`, as in `time lua path/to/script.lua` can also give different useful timings (these will include the startup time).